# Move columns matching header string to end of file with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a delimited file with 2000+ columns. I would like to rearrange the columns (and all rows under this header) by moving those that match a certain pattern to the end of the file.

My input:

```
col1:aa01 col2:aa02 col3:nn08 col4:aa03 col5:nn08 col6:aa04
value1    value2    value3    value4    value5    value6
```

Want columns ending in 'nn08' moved to the end:

```
col1:aa01 col2:aa02 col4:aa03 col6:aa04 col3:nn08 col5:nn08
value1    value2    value4    value6    value3    value5
```

This is what I have assembled from the forums so far but obviously it's not working:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {a ~ /nn08/; for (i=2;i<NF; i++) $i=$(i+1); $NF=a; print}' in >out
```

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **awk** one-liner

```
$awk 'FNR==1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/nn08/) a[i]++; } {for(i in a){str=str $i FS; $i=""} $0=$0 FS str; $1=$1; str=""}1' file

col1:aa01 col2:aa02  col4:aa03  col6:aa04 col3:nn08 col5:nn08
```

`FNR==1{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/nn08/) a[i]++; }` : For first row i.e header , iterate through each field and `if($i~/nn08/)` is true then set value of `a[i]`. `a` is an associative array where `i` would be it's key and value would be incremented (0 initially if key doesn't exist)
For eg. for 3rd column `a[3]=1` and similary `a[5]=1` for fifth column. The aim if to store the column numbers as keys in `a` which needs to be shifted.

`{for(i in a){str=str $i FS; $i=""} $0=$0 FS str; $1=$1; str=""}1`
Next, based on each key/column field number `i` stored in `a` append the column value `$i` to end `str` variable and set `column` to `null` i.e `$i=""`.  After loop, append the `str` to whole record `$0`.

Note : `$1=$1` forces awk to reform whole record which removes the extra FS (spaces) created while we were truncating the field via `$i=""`.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough but the file has hundreds of rows. I'd like to move the whole column (header + all rows under this header) to the end. Right now, the code prints the header (col3:nn08, col5:nn08) at the end of each row.

Comment: @berge2015 You mean based on the output of first row/header you want to carry out changes for all rows below it ?

Comment: yes, essentially. the rows don't have the same pattern though. edited my question for clarity. thanks.

Comment: works great. thank you sir! so you're adding 'i' into array 'a' whenever nn08 matches, printing that line, and FNR resets the array as it moves to a new line. is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
awk '{t = "";for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){if(FNR==1 && $i ~ /:nn08$/){h[i] = $i}if( i in h){t = ( t ? t OFS :"" ) $i;continue;}printf("%s%s",$i, OFS)}print t}' infile
```

Better Readable:

```
awk '
    {
      t = "";
      for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      {

          # store column index in array h
          if(FNR==1 && $i ~ /:nn08$/){
                   h[i] = $i
          }

          # if column to be skipped then
          if( i in h)
          {
             # concatenate variable
             t = ( t ? t OFS :"" ) $i;

             # continue
             continue;      
          }

          # if ok, then print such column
          printf("%s%s",$i, OFS)
      }

      # print rest of them saved in variable
      print t
    }
    ' infile
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
col1:aa01 col2:aa02 col3:nn08 col4:aa03 col5:nn08 col6:aa04
value1    value2    value3    value4    value5    value6
```

Output:

```
$ awk '{t = "";for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){if(FNR==1 && $i ~ /:nn08$/){h[i] = $i}if( i in h){t = ( t ? t OFS :"" ) $i;continue;}printf("%s%s",$i, OFS)}print t}' infile
col1:aa01 col2:aa02 col4:aa03 col6:aa04 col3:nn08 col5:nn08
value1 value2 value4 value6 value3 value5
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another one

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/:nn08$/) p[i]} 
             {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(!(i in p)) printf "%s",$i FS; 
              for(i in p) printf "%s",$i FS;
              print ""}' file
```

it can be made more efficient, but perhaps good enough as is.

Comment: yup, works great. thanks! although that ] at the end of 3rd line threw an error; removed that and ran fine.